# How can I access a Sharepoint picture library in my custom web part?

Tags: web-part, picture-library

I am looking to create a web part that simply selects a random image from a picture library and displays it. What is the accepted method for accessing images in a picture library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution through the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPPictureLibrary` class. It is a layer on top of the `SPList` class, letting you access the pictures in a picture library by manipulating the `SPListItems` in the library.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on codeplex: [SharePoint Ad Rotator](http://spadrotator.codeplex.com/releases/view/47910)

Introduction: SPAdRotator is a SharePoint Web Part that can randomly display images from a SharePoint library. Images can be displayed either one at a time (a new random image is selected every time the page is loaded), or all images can be displayed while the user is viewing the page (with a configurable transition effect).